# What is the suitable multiplier for all units?

Tags: autocad

I create Auto CAD Drawing using Primary units decimal (mm). I need to add alternative unit as Architectural. What is the suitable multiplier for all units?

[image: Modify dimension Style]

After adding new value

[image: Updated Dims]

Comment: 10 gives centimetres and 1000 gives metres. What does Autocad suggest in the help?

Comment: @SolarMike Auto cad suggest 25.4 but it is not accurate. I added 0.03937 gives me more accurate values. Thankyou

Comment: So converting from metric to imperial - lots of sources will tell you the conversion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So

1 Millimeter = 0.0393701 Inches

You can get this from many places, some being listed as holding the national standards, while others are just repeating the information. This one has some of the history and explanation which you might find useful.
from:

https://www.squareyards.com/blog/millimeter-to-inch-cnvart

Comment: Thankyou for your further clarification.

Answer (score 0):

> In 1930, the British Standards Institution adopted an inch of exactly 25.4 mm. The American Standards Association followed suit in 1933. By 1935, industry in 16 countries had adopted the "industrial inch" as it came to be known, effectively endorsing Johansson's pragmatic choice of conversion ratio.

> In 1946, the Commonwealth Science Congress recommended a yard of exactly 0.9144 metres for adoption throughout the British Commonwealth. This was adopted by Canada in 1951; the United States on 1 July 1959; Australia in 1961, effective 1 January 1964; and the United Kingdom in 1963, effective on 1 January 1964. The new standards gave an inch of exactly 25.4 mm, 1.7 millionths of an inch longer than the old imperial inch and 2 millionths of an inch shorter than the old US inch.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inch